Set query param in server component
I am using nextjs 14 in my project. The code is as follows
const selectedCategory = await getSelectedCategory(
    params.categoryKey,
  );

If the response has parent_id, i need to append it to the url.
Suppose the url is http://localhost and the selectedCategory has parent_id: 1
the url should be changed to http://localhost?parent_id=1
How to do this in a server component?
